# How to have control over backbutton hit in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the concept from below link..It worked.

[detecting browser back button in javascript/jquery without using any external plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801410/detecting-browser-back-button-in-javascript-jquery-without-using-any-external-pl)

but my problem is,
I have a dialog box which shows different input fields.
So, what i have did is when i click on back button i making that dialog to hide. But at the same time i am using the areyousure.js warning message at popup.. When i change any input field on popup and click on backbutton,I am getting a warning message as "You have unsaved changes. Stay on this page" or "leave this page." but when i click on the stay on this page the popup is getting hide as according to concept of that link.

So , what iam  trying is, when i click backbutton after changing anyfield in dialog box , i must get that warining msg and if i click stay on page it should be stay there..

When i dont change any thing just  have clicked back button i must just hide the dialog box and load the page..

Hope you all understand my problem.If so, please give me a solution.

My approach for hiding the dialog box when no changes are done on the pop up

```
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
    {
            var popDiv = $('#popupModal #progressDiv');
            var popIframe = popDiv.find('#pop-iframe');
            popIframe.hide();
    }
```

I cant do changes in my areyousure.js pages as it is used in most of the code. Some code dont have the dialogboxes..

So, in the current page , i need to valdate both the coditions..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution for you: [Detect/Warn when back button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451006/detect-warn-when-back-button-is-pressed)

Let us know if it helps

Comment: Please refrain from simply posting a link, and actually try to *answer* the question.

Comment: @NickZuber I wanted to comment, but I can't because I do not have enough rep yet. The link I posted is exactly what the OP is asking for and if you noticed it is a link to stackoverflow. I suppose the OP did not even try to search for a solution...

Comment: I have used this code already. But i am getting error at 2nd line.

Comment: can you show us your code? it is not clear to me what line 2 contains.

Comment: window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
     var ans = confirm("Are you sure?");
     if (ans) {
          //TODO: add your code here
     }
}, false);

Comment: I am getting error at  var ans = confirm("Are you sure?");

Comment: @Bhanu Can you update your question with the code throwing the error (and also add *what* the error is)? and Core-Update, OP and I appreciate you helping with a useful link but it's not fit as a standalone answer. Even though you can't comment yet, it's still considered bad to pollute the answer section with non-answers.